# Convert iso-8859-1 to utf-8 javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I try to parse a "iso-8859-1" page and save to my DB with utf-8,
this is my code:

```
var buffer = iconv.encode(data, "iso-8859-1");
data = iconv.decode(buffer, 'utf8');
```

It doesn't work. All symbols like å or ä convert to ï¿½

How can I save these symbols?

Comment: Are you sure they're not already encoded, and you're double-encoding them as a result?

Comment: if you encode to encoding X, then you need to decode from X. You can't just do `iconv.decode(icon.encode(data, "x"), "Y")`. If you want to encode in a universal format, encode to unicode and from that point in your codebase on, never convert again: DBs can store unicode, data formats can represent unicode, and data readers can do automatic unicode detection.

Comment: You seem to have `encode` and `decode` switched.

Comment: Hon2a - you should post this as the answer (I think).

Comment: hon2a, I use this library: https://www.npmjs.org/package/iconv-lite and try to convert with their examples. Anyway iconv doesn't work as I expect too... `var iconv = new Iconv('iso-8859-1', 'utf-8'); iconv.convert(data);`

Comment: Niet the Dark Absol, thank you, you are right. The problem was in double-encoding.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You need a third-party library for that task. You are using [iconv-lite](https://www.npmjs.org/package/iconv-lite) so you need to follow these steps:

1. Open input file in **binary** mode, so JavaScript doesn't assume UTF-8 nor try to convert to its internal encoding:

   ```
   var fs = require("fs");
   var input = fs.readFileSync(inputFilePath, {encoding: "binary"});
   ```
2. Convert from ISO-8859-1 to [Buffer](http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffer):

   ```
   var iconv = require('iconv-lite');
   var output = iconv.decode(input, "ISO-8859-1");
   ```
3. Save Buffer to output file:

   ```
   fs.writeFileSync(outputFilePath, output);
   ```

If unsure of encoding names, you can test whether a given encoding is supported with `encodingExists()`:

```
> iconv.encodingExists("ISO-8859-1");
true
```

Comment: It doesn't work. The case is I want to fix my subtitle issues as they are encoded in ISO-8859-1 and convert them to UTF-8. I do the thing manually by changing the Unicode of the subtitle via Firefox `view -> Text Encoding` and change it to `Arabic Windows` and replacing the fixed text into the subtitle file and save it as `UTF-8`. Automating the procedure by Node JS and your Solution DID not work for me,

Comment: @FarzadYZ That's a very specific and somehow confusing (Arabic? In Latin-1?) use case and I have no idea of what code you wrote or how your data is. This snippet merely makes the conversion asked in the question under the assumption that input data is properly encoded. (Though now I come back here two years later I realise I'm reading from a file while OP said "page" without further context.)

Answer (score 4):

It's working for me:

```
var tempBuffer = new Buffer(response.body, 'iso-8859-1');
var iconv = new Iconv('ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8');
var tempBuffer = iconv.convert(tempBuffer);
```

used 'iconv' module https://github.com/bnoordhuis/node-iconv

Answer (score 1):

You can now decode strings using the web standard `TextDecoder` (works in node & deno too):

```js
const { readFile } from 'fs'
const encoded = await readFile(inputFilePath)
const decoded = new TextDecoder('windows-1252').decode(encoded)
```

note that `windows-1252` is equivalent to `ISO-8859-1` for more, checkout https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Encoding_API/Encodings

Answer (score 0):

I want to identify the file on the picture
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsVsY.png)

The following code can make Chinese not garbled

```js
import iconv from 'iconv-lite';
var buffers = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'file/1.csv'));
var output = iconv.decode(buffers, 'gbk');
```