# Issue in decoding in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, character-encoding, string-decoding

I have a requirement where I need to encode data in "iso-8859-1" and then convert back it to readable string in node js.

In .Net env:

```
string encodedData = "VABpAG0AZQAgAHMAZQByAGUAaQBzAA==";
Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"); // encoding in "iso-8859-1"
byte[] = decodedbuff = convert.FromBase64String(encodedData);   // getting buffer
result = encoding.GetString(decodedbuff);    //decoding
```

**result = timesereis**

In a similar way, I need to encode and decode in node js

In Node js(using iconvlite)

```
const data = "VABpAG0AZQAgAHMAZQByAGUAaQBzAA=="
const buffer = iconvlite.encode(data,'iso-8859-1');
const result = buffer.toString('utf8');
```

Here in result, I am getting  **"VABpAG0AZQAgAHMAZQByAGUAaQBzAA=="**   instead of decoded result

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert iso-8859-1 to utf-8 javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27155419/convert-iso-8859-1-to-utf-8-javascript)

Comment: No, that one is different, I have to achieve it natively.

Answer (score 0):

By using the following code you get your desired result

```
let buffer = new Buffer(data, 'base64');
let result = buff.toString('utf-8');

console.log("result: "+text)
```