# How to convert Response content type from 'ISO-8859-1' to 'UTF-8'

Tags: node.js, angular

We are using NodejS for our application. One of the external service is returning a response as content type -  'text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1'. The response is something like this.

`{"name","I contain special character" ,other filed....}`.

The problem with this is for some request name contain special character inside. So this is breaking our system. we are looking for a way if the name in response contain special character than convert the name into UTF-8 format.
I already tried setting these to headers.

```
dataType: "json",
contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
```

But it is still not working. Can someone please help with a workaround or any solution ?

Comment: You can use something like [iconv-lite](https://www.npmjs.com/package/iconv-lite) to do the conversion.

Comment: can you provide sample responses

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27155419/convert-iso-8859-1-to-utf-8-javascript